# How do I turn off the full file name preview in the file manager (ubuntu 20.04 gnome nautilus)?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus, filemanager

I am talking about the preview of the full name of the currently selected file at the bottom right corner: It blocks my view of the last file's attributes (circled in red).
[image]

Comment: You can turn it off temporarily by hovering the mouse over it. There is no option to turn it off completely in the Preferences, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Jos That is a full answer to this question. You may want to turn this into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to do this.

The box is shown when you select one or more items in the file list. If your window is not high enough to show some blank space under the last item in the list, the last item will partly be covered by this box.

However (in case you hadn't noticed), the box will disappear when you hover the mouse over it, and return when you move the mouse away.